# how i can downcasting in python3?

Tags: python, class

I have two class like this :

**Super class**

```py
class A(object):
 def __init__(self,param1):
  self.param1 = param1
 
 def display(self):
  print("param1 :",self.param1)
```

**Sub Class**

```py
class B(A):
    def __init__(self,param1,param2):
        super().__init__(param1)
        self.param2 = param2
    def display(self):
        print("param1 :",self.param1," and ","param2 :",self.param2)
```

if i have an object of class A how can I convert it to an object of class B?

**Exemple of utilisation**

```
a = A(1)
#convertion here to add param2
a.display() # result -> 'param1 : 1 and param2 : 2'
```

Comment: You'll have to give us a usage example, as it is now you question makes little sense in Python.

Comment: btw Both `A` and `B` are classes, but `A` is the **Super class** and `B` is the **Sub class**, or derived class.

Comment: You can't "convert" the object type. You could either create a new object, or you could use design patterns or use late binding to override the method in the object. (Hint: prefer design patterns.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem as follows (especially to honor pylance type checking)

```
Class Action:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    def asNNaction(self)->NNaction | None:
        return None

class NNaction(Action):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    def asNNaction(self)->NNaction | None:
        return self

usage:
    def foo(action: Action):
        okAction: NNaction | None=action.asNNaction()

        assert okAction is not None, 'invalid use of an action as an NNaction
```

#proceed to use okAction as an NNaction with no objection from pyLance